# Rejected edit asking me to answer the question that is actually closed. I’m confused about how to do that

Tags: discussion

I took a long time to find a way to contribute to a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959211/what-is-the-fastest-factorial-function-in-javascript) that is closed.
[image: closed]

Hence I followed the above suggestion to try to improve this question.

But my [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/27862188) was rejected like if robots were in charge, not reading my comment, therefore not helpful.
[image]

I tried to imagine someone to find the question searching the web. And after reading all comments and answers, created a solution to compare them, thereby responded the very author question and gave community who would ask the same, a helpful shortcut.

Could a human being actually give me an answer about :

- is my contribution considered of no interest or off-topic and
  why ?
- if it is worthy, how could it be added to a closed question
  that, by judging all the answers and views number, arouses interest of the community ?
- I haven’t been notified of the rejection. Do you know if I need to enable some option in my settings ? (Ok I wasn’t following the topic. It may be the cause.)

*Note : english is not my native language. Please be indulgent if my message is not totally intelligible or sounds harsh or else.*

**Edit : Thanks for the answers. I get it. I got it wrong thinking that the original topic, that pops out when one asks this question to a search engine, could be improved since it’s irrevocably closed and thus won’t accept any new contributions.**

Comment: Yeah, that notice is a bit misleading. Lots of closed questions just can't be edited to be made on-topic without significant changes, and significant changes require the OP to do so themselves.

Comment: (not that that question looks that off-topic to me, but still - leave significant changes to the OP)

Comment: @CertainPerformance Do you mean original question about factorial function in JavaScript is off-topic or my edit or my question here ?

Comment: I’m referring to the other question. For the general case, the sorts of edits that are significant enough to bring a closed question to an on-topic question should usually be done only by the OP - the banner is misleading. Maybe the “You can edit this question…” should be shown only to the OP. (Whether this particular question deserves to be closed is another issue.)

Comment: The edit was rightfully rejected because *it adds the answer to the question body*, which is not how Stack Overflow as a Q&A site works. Answers should go to the Answers section no matter how. If the question is closed, then it should be reopened first (whether it's well-scoped or not is another issue), then you can post the answer.

Comment: You tried the same thing back on [October 18th](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/27416172) and it was correctly rejected then. You don't get to bypass site moderation by editing your answer into a question.

Comment: “But my edit was rejected like if robots were in charge, not reading my comment, therefore not helpful.” - Your edit was an attempt to provide a reply, that is literally one of the canned reasons, to reject an edit proposal.  Additionally, you shouldn’t answer a question, by providing an edit to a question.  Questions shouldn’t have their answer, contained within the body of the question.  They should be answered. If they are closed they should be edited so they can be reopened with a proper substantial edit

Comment: The question your trying to answer is closed because it doesn’t meet the minimum requirements for a question.  It’s simply not eligible to be deleted due to the number of votes the answer received otherwise it probably would have been deleted years ago

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might be wrong, but it seems like you tried to edit the question with the answer TO the question. The question should never contain the answer. If the question was closed you can either ask the mods to open it, or edit it and make it a better question. The problem with questions like this is, that they are often too open to answer, and it is very unlikely that you can guess what the original poster meant so even if you edited the question to be good it would still likely not be what he meant. Here it is less extreme, as the question has a rather clear answer, but in general this is the case, doing large edits to questions like this I'd say doesn't often end well and is probably a waste of time.

But this here is something else as you tried to answer a closed question by editing the answer into the question. That's not how things should be done.

You basically cannot answer a closed question, there is a reason questions get closed, so as I said all you can do here is ask the moderators to open it again, I think you can flag it and ask for moderator intervention to open it, but this is a rather popular closed question, so I am pretty sure the decision is final.

Comment: Please do not flag questions and request that moderators re-open them. Such flags will almost always be rejected, unless you can provide a *very* compelling justification. Closing and reopening questions is something handled mostly by the community. No moderator intervention is required in this process.